# Wondering if adding dependencies using api instead of implementation does increase Android apk size?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So we should prefer to use implementation instead of api in build.gradle wherever it's possible.
As it can affect build times. I am wondering let's say we have a project A ,it has a dependency to module B .If module B has a lot of unnecessary dependencies added by `api` instead of implementation. As I understand it would affect the build times. but can it increase the apk size as well, if yes? can you explain it?

Comment: No I think. Basiclly using implementation can reduce build time and good for architecture. Some dependencies can not access or call from other module

Comment: Thanks but why you think no , please can you clarify?